# Dead link in an absolutely positioned div

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe, absolute, broken-links

I'm trying desperately to make the link on a linked image work but whenever I click on the link, my browsers (Chrome & Firefox) just tell me they are connecting to the page and I get a continuous spinning image as if the browser were doing something. The link works perfectly if I open in another tab.

The div in question is coded and styled in a Wordpress page. I am making changes to another developer's work for a customer.

Here's the div:

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 645px; left: 80px; width: 150px;">
  <a href="http://themoneycouple.com/?p=4681" target="_top" style="display:inline-block">
    <img src="http://themoneycouple.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/kit-history.png" alt="Toolkit History Link" width="150" height="170" style="position:relative; display:block; z-index:999999999999;" />
  </a>
</div>
```

And here's the page it's on: http://themoneycouple.com/resources/love-and-money-kit/

I've tried changing the z-index on every element in multiple ways, tried changing the link target in every way possible, changed display settings, etc.

One last note, there are lots of iframes on this page and I'm not sure if those are messing things up somehow. Massive thanks for any help.

Comment: What link on the website are you talking about?

Comment: The z-index shouldn't be affecting the page not loading. However, because the video embed appears to be coming in through Flash, you'll need to change that embed to allow other content to appear over it.

As for the page not loading, it looks like Fancybox is choking on a 301 redirect. Is it possible to update the link in question with the new URL and see if that helps things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the URL for that HREF is trying to load a page as a modal using the fancybox protocol. Is this what is expected?

Does that page ID exist? It looks URL looks different from the other page URLs on the site.

---

There is a jQuery function that targets every IMG tag w/ an A tag and applies a class of "fancybox". Modify the specificity of this function to exclude the last item in the gallery. Better yet, create a new class and add it to the elements that should have the fancybox functionality. The same issue happens on other pages where the HREF goes to a page instead of opening an image.

Current jQuery function:

```
var thumbnails = jQuery("a:has(img)").not(".nolightbox").filter( function() { return /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$/i.test(jQuery(this).attr('href')) });

thumbnails.addClass("fancybox").attr("rel","fancybox").getTitle();
```

Comment: If you read the question carefully or visit the page yourself you could have seen that the page OP is trying to load via Fancybox does exist

Comment: @putvande only the new comments reference anything to do with fancybox, It is also not obvious by looking at the code supplied. There is only a reference to a spinning image and lots of iframes, I don't think this deserved a downvote.

Comment: In either case, this does not answer the question and should be posted as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: You are correct, the page does exist. But the URL reference is different from other URLs. However, OP doesn't state if the page should open in the fancybox modal or not. If that is the expected behavior, then a different resolution needs to be suggested.

Comment: There is Fancybox class added to the link automatically. I checked the settings for that plugin and it is set to "Make a gallery for all images on the page (default)"

I don't even know what that plugin does or what the implications would be of changing this setting for the entire site. Is there an easy way to turn off the effect on this page or element?

I've tried the link with both the shortlink and the full link (http://themoneycouple.com/resources/love-and-money-kit/) the same thing happens.

Comment: The jQuery is creating a var of "thumbnails" and is targeting every IMG tag with an A tag around it and automatically adds a class of "fancybox". Modify the specificty of the script target and the link should open up normally. I'll update my answer to include the code sample for you.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! The problem was solved by turning off the JQuery plugin. You guys rock.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the link you mean and it has a `fancybox` class on it, so I presume it is trying to open a `fancybox` javascript plugin popout for your link.. which is a redirect and failing to do so, since I can right click the link and go to `open in new tab` and it works.

Comment: The link also works if javascript is disabled. (Maybe this is obvious, given this answer.) Otherwise, I get these errors: `NetworkError: 403 Forbidden` for `load_scripts.php` and `SyntaxError: syntax error <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">`.